# How to save user settings for lock screen?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have developed a windows phone application which works fine when it is active. But now I want to run the same application even when the screen is locked.

I know we have to use the following code to achieve the same.

PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;

But how do I save the setting change that user make for "run under lock screen" toggle option.So that next time when user launches this app again I will set it to the settings that user made last time.

One way I figured out was using the IsolatedStorageSettings. Let me know if there is a better way to save user settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IsolatedStorageSettings is fine.